# Images keep moving around

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My theme came with a slider on the homepage and the images for the previous and next keep moving up and down.

How to reproduce:
Go to a page on [my site](http://bitsybride.com/category/wedding-cakes/). 
Click on the header logo to get to the homepage. 
Hit f5. This is where the left and right swirls are supposed to be.

The theme creator has not responded and doesn't have any forum for help. Can you tell me what modifications I should make to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
stepcarousel.setup({
galleryid: 'mygallery', //id of carousel DIV
beltclass: 'belt', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
panelclass: 'panel', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
panelbehavior: {speed:400, wraparound:true, persist:true},
defaultbuttons: {enable: true, moveby: 3, leftnav: ['<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/prev.png', -90, 120], rightnav: ['<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/next.png', 15, 120]},
statusvars: ['statusA', 'statusB', 'statusC'], //register 3 variables that contain current panel (start), current panel (last), and total panels
contenttype: ['external'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['external', 'path_to_external_file']
 })

</script>
```

Can I do something with the css to fix the position?

```
#mygallery{ padding:0;position: relative;}

.stepcarousel{
position: relative; /*leave this value alone*/
overflow: scroll; /*leave this value alone*/
width: 980px; /*Width of Carousel Viewer itself*/
height:300px; /*Height should enough to fit largest content's height*/
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}

.stepcarousel .belt{
position: absolute; /*leave this value alone*/
left: 0;
top: 0px;
}

 .stepcarousel .panel{
float: left; /*leave this value alone*/
overflow: hidden; /*clip content that go outside dimensions of holding panel DIV*/
margin:0 40px 0 0;
border:none;
  }


 .thumb-title{
top:-105px;
right:0;
display:block;
position:absolute;
width: 250px; height:68px;
background: #eee url(images/line-h-l.png) top repeat-x;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px #333;
}   



 .thumb-title-clear{
padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
height:48px;
overflow:hidden;
}

 .thumb-title h2 a {
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:16pt;
line-height:18pt;
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
font-weight:bold;
}

 .thumb-title h2 a:hover { 
}



 .stepcarousel .slideimg{
 float: left; /*leave this value alone*/
 background: #000 /*clip content that go outside dimensions of holding panel DIV*/
 margin:0; /*margin around each panel*/
 padding:0;   
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-radius:15px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
 }
```

Comment: Try changing **moveby: 3** with any other number to see what happens.

Comment: they are not jumping for me in Chrome.  did you fix this?

Comment: the moveby:3 moves the slider by 3 images. I only have 3 images so it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I noticed.  I can reproduce the issue on your page like this: If I F5 the page then everything looks fine.  If I then resize the browser, the images immediately go to the wrong spot.  I looked in the comments of the .js file here  http://bitsybride.com/wp-content/themes/basement/js/slider.js?ver=3.4.2  and saw this on line 9:

> //** Aug 27th, 08'- Nav buttons (if enabled) also repositions themselves
>   now if window is resized

I started looking at the .js file and found that if I removed 101-105:

```
$(window).bind("load, resize", function(){ //refresh position of nav buttons when page loads/resizes, in case offsets weren't available document.oncontentload
    config.offsets={left:stepcarousel.getoffset(config.$gallery.get(0), "offsetLeft"), top:stepcarousel.getoffset(config.$gallery.get(0), "offsetTop")}
    config.$leftnavbutton.css({left:config.offsets.left+config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[1]+'px', top:config.offsets.top+config.defaultbuttons.leftnav[2]+'px'})
    config.$rightnavbutton.css({left:config.offsets.left+config.$gallery.get(0).offsetWidth+config.defaultbuttons.rightnav[1]+'px', top:config.offsets.top+config.defaultbuttons.rightnav[2]+'px'})
})
```

that the Left/Right swirls would no longer 'jump' when loading or when resizing.  I stepped through the code and saw that the "offsetTop" was being changed somewhere.

So  . . .  all that to say, try and edit your setup script to include a specific "offsetTop".  I think that it is being 'guessed' somewhere in the code.  It would look exactly like this:

```
stepcarousel.setup({
    galleryid: 'mygallery', //id of carousel DIV
    beltclass: 'belt', //class of inner "belt" DIV containing all the panel DIVs
    panelclass: 'panel', //class of panel DIVs each holding content
    panelbehavior: {speed:400, wraparound:true, persist:true},
    defaultbuttons: {offsetTop: 242, enable: true, leftnav: ['http://bitsybride.com/wp-content/themes/basement/images/prev.png', -90, 120], rightnav: ['http://bitsybride.com/wp-content/themes/basement/images/next.png', 15, 120]},
    statusvars: ['statusA', 'statusB', 'statusC'], //register 3 variables that contain current panel (start), current panel (last), and total panels
    contenttype: ['external'] //content setting ['inline'] or ['external', 'path_to_external_file']
})
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work. Also, when I deleted those lines from the .js file (just to see what would happen), the swirls completely disappeared.

Comment: ok. i removed the right part. now they are fixed vertically but move horizontally. they seem to be anchored to the left side. any idea how to fix that?